# Calculate new fields with aliases in SQL

Tags: sql, alias, integer-arithmetic

Hello I am working with some sports gambling data and trying to divide columns in order to try to calculate averages and other statistics, basically I want to create a new column to calculate the following --> Covered/(Covered+Loss+Push) as Covered_Average.  I feel doing this in excel a lot easier but wondering if effecient way to this in SQL.

```
select g1.team_id, t.abbreviation,
     count(case when cast(g2.pts as float)-cast(g1.pts as float) < cast(spread2 as float) then 'Covered' end) as Covered,
     count(case when cast(g2.pts as float)-cast(g1.pts as float) > cast(spread2 as float) then 'Loss' end) as Loss,
    count(case when cast(g2.pts as float)-cast(g1.pts as float) = cast(spread2 as float) then 'Push' end) as Push 
     from nba_games_all g1
     left outer join nba_games_all g2 on g1.game_id = g2.game_id
     and g1.team_id =g2.a_team_id
     left join nba_teams_all t on t.team_id=g1.team_id
     left join nba_betting_spread bs on g1.game_id = bs.game_id
     and book_name = 'Bovada'
     left join nba_betting_money_line ml on g1.game_id = ml.game_id
     and ml.book_name = 'Bovada'
     where g1.season_year = '2017' 
     and g1.season_type = 'Regular Season'
     and g1.fg_pct >= '0.5'
     and g1.game_date >= Convert(datetime, '2017-11-02')
     group by g1.team_id, t.abbreviation
     order by Covered desc
```

Comment: Which table are you getting the column 'spread2' from?

Comment: Also, can you explain your join between g1 and g2? You've joined on game_id (so presumably the same game?) but also joined on g1.team_id =g2.a_team_id: the home team (team_id) equals the away team (a_team_id)? This makes no sense to me - if that's what your logic is

Comment: spread2 is coming from 'nba_betting_spread'.  In 'nba_games_all' there is only one column per record with the score outcome but I need both scores (pts) to compare.  game_id  appears twice in 'nba_games_all'.  So if you want to know the outcome of the game and compare the pts to the spreads you need to join it twice unless there is an easier way,  I am relearning SQL so not all is perfect

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. Also, I don't understand why you have included a join to nba_betting_money_line as you don't appear to be using the data from this table anywhere. It would probably be easier if you could provide the table definitions (create statements) for the tables involved, some sample data and the output that you expect from that sample data.

Comment: I attached nba_betting_money_line bc I was comparing spreads and moneylines in other similar queries so i left it in.  Do you have any insight on my original posted question?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write the query something like this:

```
 SELECT
 g1.team_id
 , t.abbreviation
 , CASE
        WHEN CAST(g2.pts AS FLOAT)-CAST(g1.pts AS FLOAT) < CAST(spread2 AS FLOAT) then 'Covered'
        when CAST(g2.pts AS FLOAT)-CAST(g1.pts AS FLOAT) > CAST(spread2 AS FLOAT) then 'Loss'
        when CAST(g2.pts AS FLOAT)-CAST(g1.pts AS FLOAT) = CAST(spread2 AS FLOAT) then 'Push'
        ELSE 'Error'
   END as 'clp'
 ,count(g1.came_id) as 'game_count'
 FROM nba_games_all g1
 INNER JOIN nba_games_all g2 ON g1.game_id = g2.game_id AND g1.team_id = g2.a_team_id
 INNER JOIN nba_betting_spread bs ON g1.game_id = bs.game_id
 INNER JOIN nba_teams_all t ON g1.team_id = t.team_id
 WHERE
    g1.season_year = '2017' 
    AND g1.season_type = 'Regular Season'
    AND g1.fg_pct >= '0.5'
    AND g1.game_date >= Convert(datetime, '2017-11-02')
GROUP BY
    1,2,3;
```